# I don't get how to add Web References in Windows Phone RT

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

Hey folks? I have a doubt about to use web services on Windows phone 8.1 RT without being Silverlight. When I go to select " Add Web Reference "It does not Appear for me. I want to use Windows Phone RT, is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Service Reference (specifically the System.ServiceModel namespace) is not supported in Windows Phone 8.1 RT. There's a possible workaround here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/myamama/2014/06/24/workaround-to-adding-service-reference-to-windows-phone-8-1-runtime-app/

I got around the problem by manually building a SOAP client wrapper class, and manually building the service request for each API call. It's laborious but it works...

Comment: Thank you! It worked.

I had seen this site and I implemented the same way, but wondered if there was another way.

Answer (score 0):

What about

Add Service Reference -> Advanced -> Add Web Reference -> and fill out the rest from there.

It is explained with images (for an older version of the IDE, VS2008) [here](http://www.nitrix-reloaded.com/2010/06/13/add-web-reference-and-add-service-reference-differences/)